# How do I complete download?

Tags: kubuntu

I want to exchange my XP for Kubuntu. However, I'm not very well versed with computers. I downloaded Kubuntu thinking it would automatically erase my windows XP and replace it. It took about 20 minutes to download but now I can't find it. I did a 'search'' and many Iso files turned up, but none that I could recognise as Kubuntu. What do I do now? Please make suggestions simple and in plain talk. Thank you.

Comment: What's the link that you downloaded it from? The official link is http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download. From there you choose either to download the 32 bit or 64 bit image (.iso) file.

Answer (score 2):

The Kubuntu download is an ISO file, which you can download [here](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu).

You've to burn this file to a DVD (using [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) for example) or put it on an USB drive (using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) for example). You **cannot** just copy the ISO file itself to a DVD or USB drive, this way your DVD or USB drive won't be bootable.

Then you have to start your pc from the bootable DVD or USB drive you've just created. Click [here](http://lifehacker.com/5991848/how-to-boot-from-a-cd-or-usb-drive-on-any-pc) for a tutorial about booting from DVD or USB drive.

When you've booted your Kubuntu ISO you'll see Kubuntu's graphical installer and you can just follow the on-screen instructions.

**Note:** some older PCs don't support booting from USB drives. Sometimes it's not enabled in your BIOS and you can just enable it there (look for `Legacy USB Support` or something like that). Otherwise you'll have to boot your Kubuntu ISO using a DVD.